# Bootstrap toggle button does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="NaviController">
        <div class="row main-navi uppercase navilinks" >

            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-3 ">
                <div  id="logo-container">
                    <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="assets/images/logo.svg"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-7">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#epic-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-4 navbar-collapse mainlinks"  id="epic-navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="mainlinks-container" >    
                <li class="white-shadow mainlink" ><a href="#about" data-target="about" id="about" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">About</a></li>
                <li class="mainlink"><a href="#values" data-target="values" id="values" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">Values</a></li>
                <li class="mainlink"><a href="#team" data-target="team" id="team" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">Team</a></li>
                <li class="mainlink"><a href="#portofolio" data-target="portfolio" id="portofolio" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="mainlink"><a href="#join" data-target="join" id="join" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">Join</a></li>
                <li class="mainlink"><a href="#contact" data-target="contact" id="contact" ng-click="CollapseNavilinks()">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On 320x480, 480x800, 640x960 everything works fine. But when the width becames bigger lets say 768 the button stops working.

**css and html code: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=iqyQopTpQT**

Any idea why this is happening?

Even if I try the example from [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) on 768x1280 resolution the toggle button appears but when you click it, it doesn't work.

Comment: The jsfiddle you provide does not reproduce the behaviour you are explaining. You should correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the bootstrap.css got me this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I think there are some other references for .navbar-toggle in css and js files that make it only working in browser with width < 768.

I've just tried to use the whole page from official web-site with navbar, and, that seems little bit strange, i can see the toggle button only with 767px as browser's width, not 768px.

Comment: Well, of course. That's because the toggle button only works on mobile views, which are below 767px.

Comment: But as topic starter mentioned: 

"...example from bootstrap website on 768x1280 resolution the toggle button appears but when you click it, it doesn't work". 

So I think that is strange. Why does he see it? How can he see it even when css says that he can't?

Comment: the problem was in my css, the navbar shouldnt toggle on that resolution.

Comment: So if problem is resolved you can edit your answer and somehow mark your question as solved.