# Toggle button appears but does not toggle when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a toggle button in Bootstrap. At low widths, the toggle button does show, however, it does not respond whenever I click it. At high widths the menu just shows on the top right, which works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1">
<title>Welcome</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styling.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay loop muted id="bgvideo"><source src="videos/Sea%20top%20view.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

    <!--Create navigation bar with srollspy-->
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mynavBar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Company page</a>
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarCollapse" datatoggle="collapse">

                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#promise">Promise</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div>
    </div>


    <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/j
query.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to not only show the toggle button, but also let it show the menu whenever I click it?

I checked:

[Bootstrap toggle not button does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603680/bootstrap-toggle-button-does-not-work) However, there the problem is that it doesn't work at certiain widths. Mine doesn't work in general.

[Bootstrap 3.3.2 navbar dropdown menu toggle not clickable on mobile or desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463614/bootstrap-3-3-2-navbar-dropdown-menu-toggle-not-clickable-on-mobile-or-desktop) Gave the suggestion that the jQuery scripts needs to be included before the Bootstrap script. However, this is the case for my code already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add  `data-toggle="collapse"` to the collapse button like this

```
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mynavBar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Company page</a>
                 <button data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                  <!-- remaining button code -->
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- your collapse div code -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```